# Access s3 in html file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have an HTML file which contains screenshots of automation test run. These screenshots are stored in an s3 bucket. I will be attaching this HTML file to an email. Hence will like these screenshots to be rendered and be visible to anyone who opens the HTML report on their laptop.
The challenge
- I am behind a corporate firewall hence cannot allow public access to the s3 bucket

I can access the s3 bucket via IAM access from ec2-instance and will be uploading the screenshots to s3 using the same.

I am currently exploring the following options

1. Accessing S3 via a cloudfront url (not sure regarding the access control policies available via cloudfront). This option will require lots of back forth with IT hence would be a last resort
2. Embed javascript in the HTML file to access a hosted service on EC2. This service then fetches the objects from S3.

Comment: You corporate firewall has nothing to do with S3 access for other users. You can create a policy that allows read access for anyone.

Comment: Consider creating a new S3 bucket, hosting your web page and screenshots in the S3 bucket, enable static website hosting for the bucket, and finally simply email a link (rather than an inline HTML page) to interested parties.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply set the View only Public policy(refer bottom). That will allow anyone accessing and view the Images having correct URL.

> Accessing S3 via a cloudfront url (not sure regarding the access control policies available via cloudfront). This option will require lots of back forth with IT hence would be a last resort

In my opinion this is not a correct solution. It is over engineering.

> Embed javascript in the HTML file to access a hosted service on EC2. This service then fetches the objects from S3.

In my opinion this also unnecessary overhead, you may be dealing with.

Simple, solution will be--

1. Allow Public GET Only access. SO whomsoever having full path correct URL will be able to access, in your case it will be embeded HTML report that will have links of S3, sometthing like https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/somepath/somepath/../someimage.jpg
2. Create some complicated URL pattern, so that no one could guess it easily, hence no security breach.

Public access policy will look something like below.

```
{
"Version":"2012-10-17",
 "Statement":[
  {
  "Sid":"AddPerm",
  "Effect":"Allow",
  "Principal": "*",
  "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
  "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
}    ]    }
```